# Objects are not valid as a react child (In Internet explorer 11 for React 15.4.1)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, internet-explorer-11

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, type, key, ref, props, _owner, _store}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of `App`.

AppContainer :

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Component:

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
        );
    }
}
```

Above is my render function for app.js. This Code is working fine in google chrome, but when coming to Internet explorer It is not working and it is throwing the above error.

Comment: What is {this.props.children}? a single value or an array?

Comment: yes tell us what is coming as `this.props.children`?

Comment: $$typeof : Symbol(react.element) _owner: ReactCompositeComponentWrapper _self:null _source:null _store:Object key:null props:Object ref:null ,This is the Object (this.props.children)

Comment: I assume that you researched your question on Stackoverflow and the web before posting. Tell us what you found and why it didn't help? See [Before You Ask](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#before).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

#### A problem since React 15.4 with IE11

If you still have this issue, you may have a look at [this react issue #8379 about React 15.4 and IE11](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/8379).
I had the same problem with webpack dev mode / IE11 / React 15.4, and it seems that React and ReactDom each use their version of a Symbol polyfill (this is new with 15.4):

> Somehow react and react-dom no longer "agree" on the `$$typeof` value
>
> which should be `typeof Symbol&&Symbol.for&&Symbol.for("react.element")||60103`.

#### Solution

I've resolved this issue by reordering `polyfill` and `react` / `react-dom` to be sure that the polyfill Symbol is loaded before React and ReactDom's Symbol... Now they "agree" on $$typeof value.

Example solution for webpack:

```
entry: [
 'babel-polyfill', // Load this first
 'react-hot-loader/patch', // This package already requires/loads react (but not react-dom). It must be loaded after babel-polyfill to ensure both react and react-dom use the same Symbol.
 'react', // Include this to enforce order
 'react-dom', // Include this to enforce order
 './index.js' // Path to your app's entry file
]
```

Comment: I think your solution is near to my problem, I ve ES6.polyfill() in my code.How can I override the React and ReactDoms symbol?

Comment: Note that my react and react-dom versions are 15.4.1

Comment: You have to make sure your ES6.polyfill() code is loaded after React and ReactDom are loaded. Try to debug to see which lib is loaded first, then change your webpack configuration if needed.

Comment: @FrançoisMaturel that seems incorrect. The polyfill must come BEFORE anything else, including react and react-dom

Comment: @AvindraGoolcharan thanks for pointing this out, did not check it.

Comment: I've moved my babel-polyfill import statement to after my react and react-dom imports and now my project is working. I see no side effects with any calls to Object.assign() or anything else covered by the polyfill. If anyone else is, please say so.

Comment: Is this problem fixed on any later version of React?

Comment: @RenéSchubert since the split of react / react-dom was done intentionally, I would guess the problem is still present on later versions, but did not have the opportunity to check

Comment: Incredibly this fixes also testing with Phantom JS and works for react 16 as well

Answer (score 8):

In my case with React Native we dragged this mysterious bug for weeks appearing just on Android builds without an attached debugger.

The **culprit** was an

`import 'core-js'`

on our root component, it seems the *polyfill* was messing things up

The solution was to simply remove it as it's no longer necessary in my case

Relevant portion of `package.json`

```
  "react-native": "0.44.2",
  "react": "16.0.0-alpha.6",
```

Comment: I'm getting this same issue (I don't have an import 'core-js', I'm using import 'babel-polyfill'), how did you end up solving this issue without removing your polyfill?

Comment: @jaime-agudo We have exactly the same versions of React and RN and after importing 'core-js/es6/symbol' we have the following exception on Android: 
``
'Objects are not valid as a React child ...'
``
Is it the issue that you had? How did you solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: I solved this issue by importing all polyfills in index.android.js/index.ios.js files, and delaying importing 'react' and 'react-native' until root component App.js, which is a separate file.

Answer (score 2):

My issue was babel-polyfill needed to be above my react-hot-loader includes. React and react-dom needed to preceed babel-polyfill in the webpack entry for reasons described by this comment:

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/8379#issuecomment-263962787.

Looked like this:

dev:

```
entry: [
  'babel-polyfill',
  'react-hot-loader/patch',
  `webpack-dev-server/client?${localhost}:${PORT}`,
  'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
  PATHS.app
]
```

production:

```
entry: [
  'babel-polyfill',
  'react',
  'react-dom',
  PATHS.app
]
```

Previously...

dev:

```
entry: [
  'react-hot-loader/patch',
  `webpack-dev-server/client?${localhost}:${PORT}`,
  'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
  'babel-polyfill',
  PATHS.app
]
```

production:

```
entry: [
  'babel-polyfill',
  PATHS.app
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `core-js` polyfills in my project.

The solution that ended up working for me was to add this line to the top of my `src/index.js` file:

```
import 'core-js/es/symbol'
```

Comment: This was the solution to my woes...

Answer (score 0):

**My Issue was same and was using React Native and was testing the android app on ABD device/emulator**.
After seeing suggestions from above to remove **import 'core-js'** and to add

```
entry: [
 'babel-polyfill', // Load this first
 'react-hot-loader/patch', // This package already requires/loads react (but not react-dom). It must be loaded after babel-polyfill to ensure both react and react-dom use the same Symbol.
 'react', // Include this to enforce order
 'react-dom', // Include this to enforce order
 './index.js' // Path to your app's entry file
]
```

to android/app/build.gradle file, my issue was not resolved As i didn't had any of the import statement like **import 'core-js'** or  **import 'babel-polyfill'** initially in my code.

**

Solution:

**
Insted of removing import statement i added the **import 'core-js';** to my root directory which was index.js. With manually adding the library through command Prompt/Terminal.
This solved my issue.Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I started my project with [react-slingshot](https://github.com/coryhouse/react-slingshot) and this is a solution that worked for me:

```
# from https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/master/packages/react-app-polyfill   
$ npm install react-app-polyfill --save
```

Then in the `webpack.config.js` file

```
entry: [
    'react-app-polyfill/ie11', // <==== Important line and must be loaded before you code does
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.js')
],
target: 'web',
mode: 'development',
plugins: [
...
```

You can see the full documentation here: [react-app-polyfill](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/master/packages/react-app-polyfill)

Hope this also works for you guys!