# "Objects are not valid as a React child" appear only in IE

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer

Objects are not valid as a React child. If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of Root.

This bug only appear in IE, i know a react child can't be an object, but i can't find any error in Root class

```
// Root.js
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux'
import routes from './routes'

export default class Root extends Component {
  render() {
    const { store } = this.props


    const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store)

    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <div>
          <Router history={history} routes={routes} />
        </div>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}



//  routes.js

import React from 'react'
import { Route } from 'react-router'

import Cookie from './libs/cookie'
import App from './app'
import MobileRouter from './routes/mobile'
import WebRouter from './routes/web'

export default (
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    { WebRouter }
    { MobileRouter }
  </Route>
)



// App.js

import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props

    return (
      <div>
        { children }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Show the `routes` component please.

Comment: I have added routes add app component code

Comment: I think problem is here,  `{ WebRouter }{ MobileRouter }`. What are `MobileRouter ` and `WebRouter `?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Objects are not valid as a react child (In Internet explorer 11 for React 15.4.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40897966/objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child-in-internet-explorer-11-for-react-15-4-1)

Answer (score 1):

## **Why**

If you are using react-hot-loader v3 for hot-reloading in DEV environment you need to load react-hot-loader/patch after babel-polyfill does.

So Webpack's entry field should look like the following to work correctly with react 15.4.x, react-hot-loader v3 and webpack-dev-server.

## **Fix**

```
entry: [
   'babel-polyfill', // Load this first
   'react-hot-loader/patch', // This package already requires/loads react (but not react-dom). It must be loaded after babel-polyfill to ensure both react and react-dom use the same Symbol.
   'react', // Include this to enforce order
   'react-dom', // Include this to enforce order
   './index.js' // Path to your app's entry file
]
```

## **Use**

It is very useful to test a feature in your DEV environment on IE. You can now access your local app, with webpack running, on IE from a VM, local network, ngrok, etc.

Answer (score -1):

> “Objects are not valid as a React child” appear only in IE

Not true. This error will appear in *all browsers* if you use an object. You mostly likely have something like the following in your code

```
{someBool && someObj}
```

where `someBool` is only coming out true based on how your application state is in IE. if you did the *same* actions in any other browser you will get the same error.

## Fix

Don't render an `object`. React can't handle it. And is giving you the correct error which you should fix i.e render something from the obj e.g.

```
{someBool && someObj.someStringProp}
```