# App fails to load on some platforms after upgrade to React 17

Tags: reactjs, webpack, loading, react-dom, core-js

After upgrade to React 17, the app fails to load on certain platforms. It still works well in modern Chrome for example, but fails in older browsers. It fails in the ReactDOM.render function in the entry file of the app, with the following error:

> Error: Minified React error #31; visit
> [https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=31&args[]=object%20wi…ys%20%7B%24%24typeof%2C%20type%2C%20key%2C%20ref%2C%20props%2C%20_owner%7D](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=31&args%5B%5D=object%20wi%E2%80%A6ys%20%7B%24%24typeof%2C%20type%2C%20key%2C%20ref%2C%20props%2C%20_owner%7D)
> for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full
> errors and additional helpful warnings.

Going there gives this additional information:

> The full text of the error you just encountered is:
> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
> {$$typeof, type, key, ref, props, _owner}). If you meant to render a
> collection of children, use an array instead.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that loading fails on those platforms that depend on core-js for polyfills. The script load order is messed up, so that core-js is not loaded first, even though it is imported first in the entry file. Possibly due to the new way React can be automatically imported, a feature now used in the app:

```
presets: [
    '@prefix/babel-preset-libx',
    [
      '@babel/preset-react',
      {
        runtime: 'automatic'
      }
    ]
  ],
```

Inspecting the JS object that causes the error shows:

**Chrome:**

```
$$typeof: Symbol(react.element)
key: null
props: {children: "TEST"}
ref: null
type: "div"
_owner: null
```

**Failing platform:**

```
$$typeof: 60103
key: null
props: Object
ref: null
type: "div"
_owner: null
```

It seems related to this issue: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/8379, and this SO question: [Objects are not valid as a react child (In Internet explorer 11 for React 15.4.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40897966/objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child-in-internet-explorer-11-for-react-15-4-1/40928047#40928047).

Just as in those, the solution is to specify script load order in webpack.config.js:

```
entry: [
 'core-js', // Should be loaded first
 // If applicable: 'react-hot-loader', // This package requires/loads react (but not react-dom).
 'react', // Include this to enforce order
 'react-dom', // Include this to enforce order
 './client.js' // Path to your app's entry file
]
```

Credits to solution by https://stackoverflow.com/users/4757672/fran%c3%a7ois-maturel in  https://stackoverflow.com/a/40928047/1158376